# SONAR static code analysis for current changes only

Tags: static, sonarqube, analysis, sonarqube-scan

Using Sonar how to do static code analysis only for current changes which i have done. for example my project 100 class/file and i made change to a class/file, now sonar has to run static code analysis only for that particular not for the entire project. how to achieve it?

Answer (score 3):

While SonarQube is used to run the analysis of your entire project, [SonarLint](http://www.sonarlint.org/) can be used to get a rapid feedback on your current development. SonarLint provides a SonarQube analyses in you favorite IDE for Java, Javascript, PHP or .Net.

Note that [SonarLint for CLI](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/SonarLint+for+Command+Line) also make you able to get in command line the difference between what is currently on your workspace and what has been analyzed during last SonarQube analysis.

Finally, some SonarQube plugins have been created to analyze pull requests for some SCM based on git:
 * [SonarQube Github plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/GitHub+Plugin)
 * [SonarQube Gitbucket plugin](https://github.com/mibexsoftware/sonar-bitbucket-plugin)
 * [SonarQube GitBucket On Demand plugin](https://github.com/mibexsoftware/sonar-bitbucket-plugin)

Comment: SonarLint for CLI seems to be decommissioned